# Unable to execute Sql query in node.js using MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Below is my server.js file content. When I try to execute it, It takes too long and finally I am getting "Error in the query!" Although accounts table contains 1 row but still something seems to be wrong. Please can any one help me with it!

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const mysql = require('mysql')
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'myDatabase',
  port: '8090'
});

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')

db.connect(function(error){
    if(!error){
        console.log('Error');
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
}) 


app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let sql ='SELECT * FROM accounts';
   
    db.query(sql,function(error, rows, fields) {
        if(!!error){
            console.log('Error in the query!');
        } else{
            console.log('Successful query');
            console.log(rows[0]);;
        }
    })
   
   
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')


app.on('close', function() {
    db.end();
});
app.listen('3000', ()=>{
    console.log('Server started on port 3000')
})
```

**Edit:**

I am getting this error:

> Error in the query! Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
> at Protocol._validateEnqueue (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:212:16)
> at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
> at Connection.query (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)

Comment: It's look as timeout issue. How many records you have in accounts table? How time get query execution directly in DB? Change your query to `SELECT * FROM accounts LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I tried that but still the same issue. It takes too long and print in the console 'Error in the query'

Comment: Add clonsole.log(error) and look what error occurred

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I am getting this error:
Error in the query!
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.

    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:212:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Connection.query (E:\Screen Sharing App\InovantisMeets\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)

Comment: Are you sure about MySQL port 8090? By default it 3306

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes I am sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223405/discussion-between-it-world-and-slava-rozhnev).